# Can not inject angular controller with factory in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Have some troubles with it. I find similar questions with solutions, but it doesn`t help me.

First of all that`s my angular scripts that I want to test.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.factory('settingsFactory', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        //factory logic here
    }
]);

app.controller('settingsCtrl', ['$scope', 'settingsFactory',
    function($scope, settingsFactory) {
        //controller logic here
    }
]);
```

And my test

```
describe('Settings Controller', function() {

var controller, scope, factory;

beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');
});

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    factory = $injector.get('settingsFactory');
    controller = $controller('settingsCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        settingsFactory: factory
    });
}));

describe('Test inject', function () {
    it("this dummy checks injecting of settings controller", function () {
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

});

And my test failure with Error: [$injector:modulerr].

Fix my brains, guys. I don`t know what happen.

Add SpecRunner.html. Suppose maybe I forget include something..

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.0</title>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

        <!-- include source files here... -->      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../angular-mocks.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../app/app.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../app/controllers/settingsCtrl.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../app/services/settingsFactory.js"></script>

        <!-- include spec files here... -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/hello-world-spec.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/controllers/settings-ctrl-spec.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

2014\03\07

Add angular-mocks.js with same version of angular.js - v.1.2.5 and get this error:
Cannot read property 'running' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`ve drunk some beer and remove angular.min.js, angular-mocks.js and download stable v1.2.14 of these angulars. And this works fine.

Use only one (stable) version of angular and drink only dark colored beer!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are missing $injector in your function params, so instead of:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    factory = $injector.get('settingsFactory');
```

use:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $injector) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    factory = $injector.get('settingsFactory');
```

Comment: "Failed to instantiate module ngMock due to:" error. I include angular-mocks.js in SpecRunner.html but it doesn`t help